# How to use Combo Box item in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have one Combo Box with different item in C#.As:

1. New Item
2. Delete Item
3. Show Item

Now I want to set different forms with each combo box item.If I click in any item then open New Item Form.

How I use this?

Comment: What does the swing tag have to do with C#?

Comment: Have a look at selection change events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event in this way:

```
//ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string selected = (string)ComboBox.SelectedItem;

    if(selected == "New Item"){
        //do something here
    }
    else if(selected == "Delete Item"){
        //do something here
    }
    else if(selected == "Show Item"){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Fuex .As u told about this code ,Now this code really work.

Answer (score 0):

In the `SelectionChanged` event, have a `switch()` command on the `selectedIndex` of the combobox, with a `case` for each option, and in the case call `newItemFormVariable.show()`

I might be getting property or event names wrong since I am doing this by heart, but you get the idea.